# Seaborn's relplot gives a ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, anaconda, seaborn

I am trying to do some relplots in seaborn. But I get VaueError. Here is my code:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, kind='scatter', hue='sex')
```

I get a long error message. I am pasting only the last part of the error message.

```
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

I am using seaborn version 0.10.0

This is the complete error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-ab3b3558717c> in <module>
----> 1 sns.relplot(data=df, x="speeding", y="alcohol", hue="abbrev")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py in relplot(x, y, hue, size, style, data, row, col, col_wrap, row_order, col_order, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, markers, dashes, style_order, legend, kind, height, aspect, facet_kws, **kwargs)
   1707         if p.legend_data:
   1708             g.add_legend(legend_data=p.legend_data,
-> 1709                          label_order=p.legend_order)
   1710 
   1711     return g

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in add_legend(self, legend_data, title, label_order, **kwargs)
    103             # Draw the plot to set the bounding boxes correctly
    104             if hasattr(self.fig.canvas, "get_renderer"):
--> 105                 self.fig.draw(self.fig.canvas.get_renderer())
    106 
    107             # Calculate and set the new width of the figure so the legend fits

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1862             self.patch.draw(renderer)
   1863             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1864                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1865 
   1866             renderer.close_group('figure')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    129     if not_composite or not has_images:
    130         for a in artists:
--> 131             a.draw(renderer)
    132     else:
    133         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py in wrapper(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    409                          else deprecation_addendum,
    410                 **kwargs)
--> 411         return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    412 
    413     return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2746             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2747 
-> 2748         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2749 
   2750         renderer.close_group('axes')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    129     if not_composite or not has_images:
    130         for a in artists:
--> 131             a.draw(renderer)
    132     else:
    133         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in draw(self, renderer)
    929     def draw(self, renderer):
    930         self.set_sizes(self._sizes, self.figure.dpi)
--> 931         Collection.draw(self, renderer)
    932 
    933 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in draw(self, renderer)
    383             else:
    384                 combined_transform = transform
--> 385             extents = paths[0].get_extents(combined_transform)
    386             if (extents.width < self.figure.bbox.width
    387                     and extents.height < self.figure.bbox.height):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py in get_extents(self, transform, **kwargs)
    601                 xys.append(curve([0, *dzeros, 1]))
    602             xys = np.concatenate(xys)
--> 603         return Bbox([xys.min(axis=0), xys.max(axis=0)])
    604 
    605     def intersects_path(self, other, filled=True):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _amin(a, axis, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     41 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
     42           initial=_NoValue, where=True):
---> 43     return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     44 
     45 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    246 
    247     if 'png' in formats:
--> 248         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    249     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    250         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    130         FigureCanvasBase(fig)
    131 
--> 132     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    133     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    134     if fmt == 'svg':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2191                            else suppress())
   2192                     with ctx:
-> 2193                         self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2194 
   2195                     bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1862             self.patch.draw(renderer)
   1863             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1864                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1865 
   1866             renderer.close_group('figure')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    129     if not_composite or not has_images:
    130         for a in artists:
--> 131             a.draw(renderer)
    132     else:
    133         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py in wrapper(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    409                          else deprecation_addendum,
    410                 **kwargs)
--> 411         return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    412 
    413     return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2746             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2747 
-> 2748         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2749 
   2750         renderer.close_group('axes')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    129     if not_composite or not has_images:
    130         for a in artists:
--> 131             a.draw(renderer)
    132     else:
    133         # Composite any adjacent images together

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in draw(self, renderer)
    929     def draw(self, renderer):
    930         self.set_sizes(self._sizes, self.figure.dpi)
--> 931         Collection.draw(self, renderer)
    932 
    933 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     39                 renderer.start_filter()
     40 
---> 41             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     42         finally:
     43             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py in draw(self, renderer)
    383             else:
    384                 combined_transform = transform
--> 385             extents = paths[0].get_extents(combined_transform)
    386             if (extents.width < self.figure.bbox.width
    387                     and extents.height < self.figure.bbox.height):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py in get_extents(self, transform, **kwargs)
    601                 xys.append(curve([0, *dzeros, 1]))
    602             xys = np.concatenate(xys)
--> 603         return Bbox([xys.min(axis=0), xys.max(axis=0)])
    604 
    605     def intersects_path(self, other, filled=True):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _amin(a, axis, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     41 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
     42           initial=_NoValue, where=True):
---> 43     return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     44 
     45 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity

<Figure size 360x360 with 1 Axes>
```

Comment: Hi, I wasn't able to reproduce this. I was using seaborn version 0.10.1.

Comment: Also not reproducible on seaborn 0.11.0. What version you are using?

Comment: If you use seaborn in a specific environment like Jupyter, Anaconda, etc., test it outside this environment to see if the error is specific to this environment. You should also post the full traceback.

Comment: What about showing us the complete error trace? Or at least the first few and the last few lines? What versions of seaborn, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, python are you running? Did you try upgrading?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your StackTrace starts with:

```
sns.relplot(data=df, x="speeding", y="alcohol", hue="abbrev")
```

So *data* parameter is *df* not *tips*.

Probably you are wrong as to what actually executes your program.

Check your *df* whether it contains the mentioned columns
(*speeding* and *alcohol*).
Or maybe your *df* is empty?

**Another hint** (found on SO): Probably the actual source of
your error is in *matplotlib* version *3.3.1*.

Check your version of *matplotlib*:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.__version__
```

If it is just *3.3.1*, upgrade it to *3.3.2*.